# Async handling using Apache Camel with RabbitMQ

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am trying to setup a small POC which can demo that Apache Camel using RabbitMQ can handle asynchronous processing.  The motivation for this is to find a way to support long running tasks which would best be suited to asynchrounous processing.  Here is my current code:

```
@Autowired
MySimpleTask task;

public void configure() throws Exception {
    restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest().get("/pipeline?route={route}").route()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "/pipeline endpoint has been hit with route = " + header("route"))
            .transform().simple("Here is some body text.")
            // intentionally make three calls to test if async works
           .to("rabbitmq://localhost/ex?routingKey=A")
           .to("rabbitmq://localhost/ex?routingKey=A")
           .to("rabbitmq://localhost/ex?routingKey=A");

    from("rabbitmq://localhost/ex?routingKey=A&autoAck=true")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Incoming content from queue: ${body}")
        .threads(20)
        .bean(task, "doSomething");
}
```

Here is the code for my task:

```
@Component
public class MySimpleTask {
    public void doSomething(String msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": doSomething() has started with message: " + msg);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": doSomething() has finished: " + msg);
    }
}
```

The dummy task I created in `MySimpleTask` is to just sleep for 10 seconds, to simulate something more meaningful actually happening later on (e.g. the OCR of an image).  What I was hoping to see from the above is that all three simple tasks would start one after the other, followed by a pause of 10 seconds, and then the completing of each of the tasks.  Instead, I see one task after the other, starting and finishing synchronously.

Can someone shed some light on how to include asynchronous support with Apache Camel running RabbitMQ as the JMS implementation?

Comment: Maybe this [page](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/async.html) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that using the to methods without changing the message exchange pattern (MEP) in your route is causing the messages to be sent one after the other (default is `InOut`). You could try changing your exchange pattern to `InOnly` to see if that has the effect you desire. Something along the lines of:

```java
public void configure() throws Exception {
    restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet")
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest().get("/pipeline?route={route}").route()
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "/pipeline endpoint has been hit with route = " + header("route"))
        .transform().simple("Here is some body text.")
        // intentionally make three calls to test if async works
        // route to an intermediate route to allow changing the MEP (can't do this in the REST DSL yet afaik)
       .to("direct://intermediateRoute")
       .to("direct://intermediateRoute")
       .to("direct://intermediateRoute");
    
    // intermediate route to change MEP
    from("direct://intermediateRoute")
        .inOnly("rabbitmq://localhost/ex?routingKey=A");
    
    from("rabbitmq://localhost/ex?routingKey=A&autoAck=true")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Incoming content from queue: ${body}")
        .threads(20)
        .bean(task, "doSomething");
}
```

Alternatively, something like the [multicast](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/multicast-eip.html) pattern may also be worth looking into.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - did this help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Apache Camel [Event Message component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/event-message.html). Simply add

> &exchangePattern=InOnly

to your Rabbitmq URL. This will ensure that your queue becomes one-way and the producer will not need to wait for the OUT message from the consumer. That in a nutshell makes your processing asynchronous.